# Let G be simple, |G| is not 2, and ϕ a homomorphism from G to H. If H contains a normal subgroup A of index 2, then ϕ(G) ≤ A .

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-homomorphism, simple-groups

Let $G$ be simple group, $|G|$ is not 2, and $ ϕ $ a homomorphism from $G$ to $H$. If $H$ contains a normal subgroup A of index 2, then $ ϕ(G) ≤ A $ .

I have been trying the following: $A$ is normal and maximal in $H$ since its index is 2(basic fact + correspondence theorem). $G$ is simple so it is isomorphic to its image so its image is a simple subgroup of $H$. Now I have to show somehow that its image must be a subgroup of $A$ and I can't find any reason it has to. I would very appreciate if someone could help me with this.

Comment: Hint: compose with the quotient map $H\to H/A$.

Comment: this is how i got that A is maximal. can i get more from that?

Comment: What's the kernel of $G\to H/A\cong\mathbb Z_2$?

Comment: G intersect A. starts to look like second isomorphisem...

Comment: i seems that the kernel must all of G because the kernel is normal in G and G is simple, otherwise |G| = 2 becuse the kernel would be trivial and by iso 1 we get |G| = 2. is it correct?

Comment: and because it is also G intersect A we conclude that G<A

Comment: $A$ and $G$ are not in the same set/group... unless $H = G$.

Comment: i was referring to ϕ(G) as G as they are isomorphic

Comment: $G$ and $\phi(G)$ are not isomorphic unless $\phi$ is injective

Comment: the kernel of ϕ is normal in G, therefore it is either trivial and in this case ϕ is injective or it equals G and in this case ϕ(G) = 1 and we are done as 1  < A

Answer (score 0):

Proof: Let $\pi : H \to H/A$ be the natural quotient map, and let $f = \pi \circ \phi: G \to H \to H/A$. 
The kernel of $f$ is the set of $g \in G$ such that $\pi(\phi(g))$ is the coset $1_HA = A$; that is the set of $g \in G$ such that $\phi(g) \in A$, which is exactly $\phi^{-1}(A)$. Since $G$ is simple, we have that $\phi^{-1}(A) = \ker(f)$ is either $\{1_G\}$ or $G$ (since kernels are normal subgroups). Since $|G| > 2$ and $|H/A|=[H:A] = 2$, the pigeon hole principle says that $f$ cannot be injective and so $\phi^{-1}(A)=\ker(f) > \{1_G\}$; hence $\phi^{-1}(A) = \ker(f) = G$. Thus $\phi(G) = \phi(\phi^{-1}(A)) \leqslant A$.